# Graph where edges represent vector (force and direction) between nodes

Tags: network-programming, networkx, graph-theory

Is there any domain (/ dedicated keyword) of graph theory that covers graphs where the edges represent forces?

Force is a vector. Thus, it has two attributes: `weight`, and `direction`.
`weight` represents the magnitude of the force.
`direction` represents the direction in which the force is acting. This direction is different from *directed graphs* where only the head or tail nodes matter.

The sense of direction can be better understood by the following examples:

**Example 1:**
Consider a network of inelastic strings under tension. Let's say the network is under equilibrium. If we pull a node, all other nodes will be pulled. Please note, the *length of the strings* (~ weight) won't change. But, the locations of the nodes and thereby the direction of the strings may change to bring all the nodes back to equilibrium after the pull.

**Example 2:** Consider all the `planets` (~nodes) in the universe in the form of a graph. All of them impart `gravitational force` (~edges) on each other and are under equilibrium. If we dislodge (or increase the size) of a planet/sun, others are likely to disturb.
The edge weight/length can represent the magnitude of force (But, direction??).

In both the example, the `direction` component differ them from traditional sense of `edge weights` where the edges are just scalars. They, do not have direction.
The scalars can be analogous to a sense of *distance* (shortest distance, eccentricity, closeness centralities) or *flow* (betweenness centrality etc.); but not force.

The question is *How to incorporate direction of edges (in addition to length/weight) in network analysis? Is there any domain that focuses on graphs where edges have weights as well as direction?*

**Note:** The `direction` of the edge can be an additional parameter like angle; or be specified by the location of the connecting nodes.

Comment: Graph theory is not concerned with the exact angles or magnitudes of weights. Planets interacting through gravitational forces on each other is a physics problem, there probably aren't any tools in graph theory that would help you analyze these problems

Comment: Graph theory includes magnitudes, as I mentioned, in the form of distance and flow.
I am also thinking from the perspective of multigraphs. Can the `direction` and `magnitude` be combined in any form for analysis?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds like force-directed graph drawing algorithms as discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing). Since you tagged this with `networkx`, the [spring_layout](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html) method uses the Fruchterman-Reingold force-directed algorithm.

The networkx documentation doesn't list an actual reference to the algorithm, but the `R` `igraph` package lists this as the reference for their `layout_with_fr` function:

Fruchterman, T.M.J. and Reingold, E.M. (1991). Graph Drawing by Force-directed Placement. Software - Practice and Experience, 21(11):1129-1164.

Comment: Force directed graphs are definitely one way to look at it. I have two more ideas to which might be useful. Still, these are limited. If there's a domain (of research) related to this, that would have been awesome